# Class member initialization order with class object as a member

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand member class initialization order but there is one thing that confusing me.

```
#include <iostream> 

class Foo {
        int y{7};
    public:
        Foo() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Foo Constructor"; 
        }

        explicit Foo(int yy) : y(yy) 
        { 
            std::cout << "Foo " << y << std::endl; 
        }

        int gety() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Foo::gety() returning "; 
            return y; 
        }
};

class Bar {
        int x;
    public:
        Bar() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Bar constructor" << std::endl; 
        }
        explicit Bar(int xx) : x(xx) 
        { 
            std::cout << "Bar "<< x << std::endl; 
        }

        int getx() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Bar::getx() returning "; 
            return x; 
        }
};

class Class {
    Bar bar;
    Foo foo;

    public:
        Class() : bar(foo.gety()), foo(5) 
        { 
            std::cout << "Class()\n";
        }
        void printxy() 
        { 
            std::cout << "Bar.x = " << bar.getx() << " \n" << "Foo.y = " <<  foo.gety() << std::endl; 
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    Class k;
    k.printxy();
    return 0;

}
```

I'm compiling this code with gcc `--std=c++11 -Wuninitialized -Wall -pedantic`

In Class object there is two members of class Foo and Bar. In initialization list I'm constructing firs `bar` object by using constructor that takes int as argument. But as i understand foo is not constructed yet because it's second in order on initialization list. So how i don't get any errors when using `foo.gety()` before it's constructed?

I think C++ is guarantee that any used object is constructed. So when `Foo` object is  constructed? Or this is undefined behavior?

This is link for coliru example: [Link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b2e4a17f77a1f2f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member variables are initialized in the order they are defined in the class. In your case `bar` will be initialized before `foo` (even if you change the order in the constructor initializer list).

What you're doing, using the uninitialized `foo` object, will lead to *undefined behavior*. There's no guarantee that a compiler will be able to catch it or even report it.